# Quick info button not appearing in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have a freshly installed visual studio code, and when the dropdown for the list members appears, I'm not seeing the quick info button. I have been having this problem mainly on my laptop, but I've gotten it to appear on my home PC. Very recently though, it doesn't even appear there.

[Screenshot of what I'm seeing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILQmT.png)

I am working within a .ipynb file, using the python extension version 2019.11.50794. I haven't (to my knowledge) messed with any of the extension settings.

[Visual Studio Code Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MocKk.png)